# How to start/stop printer?

Tags: macos, operating-system, cups, systems-programming

How do you pause/unpause a print queue using the CUPS API?  Using CUPS API I can check the printer-state using cupsGetOption().  If this returns a value of 5, I know the printer is stopped or paused.  I'd like to unpause the printer in this case, is there a way to do this?

Comment: could not resist: when I read the title the first thing that popped to mind was "use a hammer". :)

Comment: That would definitely work for stopping any incoming jobs..

Comment: Can't find any libraries that do this, but I found I could make a system call to cupsenable.

Answer (score 0):

You could use cups' ipptool to execute [ipp operations](http://www.cups.org/documentation.php/spec-ipp.html):

`#!/usr/bin/env ipptool -tv ipp://localhost/printers/your_queue
{
        OPERATION Resume-Printer
        GROUP operation-attributes-tag
        ATTR charset attributes-charset utf-8
        ATTR language attributes-natural-language en
        ATTR uri printer-uri $uri
}`

You might be asked for a password though.